# Span element overflows when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding a span elements dynamically from input field into a div. When they reached the right end of the div. It overflows in the same line.

However, when the number of span elements are pre-defined into a div element then they are not overflowed and they comes down and starts from a new line. I want this way.

I analysed both the element structure in firebug and both look same.

Here the fiddle for demonstration - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/uJj4g/1/)

Please let me know for any mistake I am doing and if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `span` is an inline element, it's affected by whitespace in the HTML.

In your predefined example, you have a line break between each `span`.

To make your JavaScript version work, you need to add some whitespace.

Add either a line break:

```js
$("#box1").append("<span>"+val+"</span>\r\n");
```

or just a space:

```js
$("#box1").append("<span>"+val+"</span> ");
```

The choices are equivalent, but your intention may be clearer with a line break.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding CSS

```
.span{
display: inline-block
}
```